# How to preserve nested collection colors on instances using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, color, instances, custom-attributes

A simple case.

- 2 cubes in a collection using same material.
- This material color is driven by an ObjectInfo node  connected to  and both cubes have actually different colors set in Object tab>Viewport Display>Color
- The collection (with two cubes) is used with the InstanceOnPoints and CollectionInfo nodes expecting to output a geometry having instantiated cubes while keeping their original material setup/colors.

I created a new material to use on geometry nodes  output replacing the ObjectInfo node by the Attribute node  to .

I am trying to sample the color attribute from the cubes using SampleIndex, or CaptureAttribute nodes but I am not sure if those attributes are passed in first place while using a CollectionInfo node.

Is there a way to output the instances having the root object Color attr driving the instancer output somehow?